# Qt winmigrate framework

Tags: qt, winapi

I tried running one of the winwidget with mingw compiler. but it keeps looking for a qmain method. I can run this example with visual studio compiler with out an issue. has anyone got any advice on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After head banging for days found a solution for this. There is a slight tweek needed to be done in order to sort this out.

Actually the component compile just fine except for the qwinwidget example. So I replaced the main method (supported by visual studio compiler) to the one supported by mingw supported main method.

//This part is for the mingw

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
}
```

//This is for the visual studio

```
int APIENTRY wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
              HINSTANCE /*hPrevInstance*/,
              LPTSTR    /*lpCmdLine*/,
              int       nCmdShow)
{
}
```

I appreciate of some one can confirm this.